# Can current flow from positive to positive in real life

Tags: voltage, transistors, batteries, electron

How to implement a circuit diagram where there are 2 batteries and negative to negative have load and postive to positive have some load.             How to implement, like build in real life this circuit& will it work (the voltages in batteries are different):
[image]

Comment: If you have a resistor, and the voltage on one side is different than the other, then current will flow from the higher voltage to the lower voltage. Some voltage sources are OK accepting current. And some are not. For example rechargeable batteries are OK with accepting current. Some power supplies will not accept current.

Comment: Positive is not an absolute thing.  Conventional current will flow from a more positive to a less positive point, if the resistance between those two points is not infinite.

Comment: It was pointed out in the comments to one of your earlier questions that you should stop talking about electrons. Just use the concept of current flowing from the higher potential to the lower. It will eliminate much confusion and you'll be able to talk to other engineers sensibly.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that current only flows if there is a potential difference. So positive to positive may only be a relative measurement if one is "more positive" than the other.
BTW, this simplification excludes superconductors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,but in real life it's proton that are in postive side so how to actually build this .?

Comment: @AamirshahSHAIK In real life, positive and negative are just arbitrary conventions. We say electricity flows from positive to negative because the scientists originally got it wrong and there was too much investment in the convention to change it. As for the circuit, just build it - it's simple enough to be an entertaining experiment

Comment: @Dirk Electric current isnt just the flow of electrons, its any charged particle. Its not right or wrong, its just a convention.

Comment: @DirkBruere it can be more entertaining than the OP probably expects, with the wrong choice of battery. Take care...

Answer (score 0):

As you say, when the battery voltages are different, yes, current will flow and the circuit can be said to "work".

HOWEVER be aware that current flowing into the lower voltage battery will charge it. So, this circuit (whatever else it does) is a battery charger.

Now if that's what you intended ... great.

However, if the lower voltage battery is not rechargeable, or already fully charged, [you will damage it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuKF8XfCVKQ), and [some types of battery don't like that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3WHIvSCrzY).